# Expressões Regulares em VBA - Extrair substring

Tags: regex, vba

No texto abaixo, gostaria de um pattern de regular expression, compatível com o VBA, para extrair o texto localizado entre o sinal de igual "=" e a primeira quebra de linha (destaque em negrito):

Cliente = **CON CLIENTE ABCD**

Regra  = Alocação em compromissadas Limite - Min. R$ 0 - ( 0,00% ) - Max. R$ 0 - ( 0,00% ) Valor Base - R$ 0,00 Valor Apurado Financeiro - R$0,00 - ( 0,00% )

Comment: e os clientes se repetem ou não? Não dá pra entender a pergunta assim, fica ampla demais.

Comment: Cliente =\s+?(.*?)\s+?\n

Comment: Qual programa Office está sendo utilizado no VBA?

Comment: Com um teste no Excel esta foi a expressão utilizada em que foi possível extrair os dados em negrito: `(?:Cliente =\s+?)(.*?)\s+?(?:Regra.+$)` e o [teste do regex](https://regex101.com/r/PiM43P/1). Pois com `Cliente =\s+?(.*?)\s+?\n` parece que o Excel não reconhece o `\n` nova linha.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, os clientes não se repetem.

Comment: @dosSantos me refiro a "chave", quero dizer é um cliente apenas ou multiplos clientes?

Answer (score 1):

> [...]gostaria de um pattern de regular expression, compatível com o VBA,
>   para extrair o texto localizado **entre o sinal de igual "="** e a
>   **primeira quebra de linha** [...]

Existem 2 maneiras de capturar isso:

- Você pode utilizar essa regex:

  `^.*?= *(.*)`
- Ou utilize essa regex **sem flag global /g** (verifique se esta
  ativada, geralmente vem ativada por *default*).

  `= *(.*)`

As duas retornarão tudo que estiver após o `=` ignorando os espaços entre ele e o primeiro caractere.
[Você pode ver o funcionamento do 1º exemplo aqui](https://regex101.com/r/PiM43P/5)
[Você pode ver o funcionamento do 2º exemplo aqui](https://regex101.com/r/PiM43P/4)

---

> Porque não usar simplesmente a sequencia "Cliente =" antes?

Usar essa sequencia com certeza daria o mesmo resultado, **porém** somente nesse exemplo.
Como o objetivo do usuário que perguntou é "**capturar entre o sinal de igual "="** e a **primeira quebra de linha** [...]" não pode ser feito algo baseado na sequencia de caracteres na primeira linha do exemplo
Acredito que o certo é usar *tokens* que representam essas condições como delimitadores para a captura, assim a regex irá apresentar os resultados desejados independente de mudanças na sequencia antes do primeiro `=`.